# Using c++17 'structured bindings' feature in visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

I'm trying to utilize some c++17 features such as structured bindings in my code but the compiler keeps giving me errors and I'm not sure if it's because I'm doing things wrong or if I haven't setup c++17 properly to work in VS17. The simple code I'm trying to compile is this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    int i = 0;
    float f = 32.0f;
};

int main()
{
    S s;

    auto [i, f] = s();

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

From the understanding of [this](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/structured-bindings/) article, this is how I would use the new c++17 syntax to return multiple values. However, I keep getting these errors:

```
c:\users\jason\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(16): error C2059: syntax error: 'empty declaration'
1>c:\users\jason\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(16): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '['
1>c:\users\jason\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(16): warning C4467: usage of ATL attributes is deprecated
1>c:\users\jason\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(16): error C2337: 'i': attribute not found
1>c:\users\jason\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(16): error C2337: 'f': attribute not found
1>c:\users\jason\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(16): error C2059: syntax error: '='
```

I've also tried setting the compiler switch to std:/c++latest inside the properties of the project but still no dice. What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: What actual version of the compiler do you have? I.e. what version do you get from running `cl /Bv`?

Comment: `auto [i, f] = s;`, non?

Comment: It's telling me version 19.00.24218.2. And I've tried `auto[i,f] = s;` as well but no luck.

Comment: "And I've tried `auto[i,f] = s;` as well" ...a hypothetical compiler supporting structured binding would compile this, but should see `auto[i,f] = s();` as an error, since `s()` is nonsense.  I think you're misunderstanding the article you linked to.

Comment: I'm getting a different error than you with VS2017. `1>c:\temp\test\test.cpp(659): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
1>c:\temp\test\test.cpp(659): error C2119: '<structured binding>': the type for 'auto' cannot be deduced from an empty initializer
1>c:\temp\test\test.cpp(659): error C3617: initializers of structured bindings must be of array or non-union class type; type 'int' is not permitted`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. As @KerrekSB noted in the comments, `auto [i, f] = s();` should be `auto [i, f] = s;`.
2. You said that you're using VS2017 but then indicated that your compiler version is 19.00.24218, which is actually VS2015 Update 3... VC++ did not support structured bindings until VS201*7* Update 3 (compiler v19.11.25503) — you need to update (or fix your project settings and/or build environment so that the correct compiler is used).

Comment: Yep. While it wasn't that I was using the VS 2015 compiler(I listed that compiler version by mistake) I realized that VS 2017 was never updated to the latest version (update 3). After doing so everything worked as expected.

Answer (score -4):

Only did a quick look at the page you linked but seems like you should have it like this:

```
    #include <iostream>

struct S
{
    int i = 0;
    float f = 32.0f;
};

int main()
{
    S s(); <--- You were missing the ()

    auto [i, f] = s();

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to compile this? `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct S __cdecl s(void)" (?s@@YA?AUS@@XZ) referenced in function _main`  If I'm not mistaken, `S s();` is a function declaration.

Comment: On the blog he linked to, `yay foo();` declares a function called `foo` that returns `yay`.  Simply mimicking the syntax isn't "the" issue; you need to understand what's going on.  And once you do, that's not the question; he's trying to get some particular version of Microsoft compiler to use this feature.

Comment: I did not. I only looked at the example at the page and compared to his example.

Comment: Ya, no matter which way I try to implement it I still get the same errors. Since it doesn't seem to matter how I implement things this leads me to believe it has something to do with the compiler not supporting this feature of c++17. Either that or there's something else I'm missing such as not enabling a particular compiler switch or something.

Comment: Most of the examples here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding work for me in VS2017. *shrug* Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but `auto[x, y] = S();` works and x, y corresponds to the default values initialized in the struct. If I implement the `yay` function in the linked article to return a default constructed struct it also works.