# Structure Binding in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, c++17

I aware that someone asked similar question but what I have seen is different error when I try to use c++17 Structure Binding in my code (e.g. for (auto [i, it] = std::tuple{ 0, nodes.begin() }; i < size; i++)), I have already set to use ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17) in project properties and checked compiler version.

Ref: [Using c++17 'structured bindings' feature in visual studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46507543/using-c17-structured-bindings-feature-in-visual-studio-2017)

**Compiler complained**
Error   C2429   language feature 'structured bindings' requires compiler flag '/std:c++17'

**My Code**

```
TreeNode* ConstructBinaryTree(const int* const intChain, size_t size)
{
    std::list<TreeNode*> nodes;

    for (auto [i, it] = std::tuple{ 0, nodes.begin() }; i < size; i++)
    {
        TreeNode* curr = (it != nodes.end())? *it : nullptr;
        TreeNode* toBeAssiged = new TreeNode(intChain[i]);
        nodes.push_back(toBeAssiged);

        if (curr)
        {
            if (curr->left)
            {
                curr->right = toBeAssiged;
                it++;
            }
            else
            {
                curr->left = toBeAssiged;
            }
        }
    }

    return (nodes.size() == 0)? nullptr : *nodes.begin();
}
```

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019

Structure binding should be supported after VS 2017 15.3 17

**My compiler version**
[image: My compiler version]

Comment: I tried the same setting and code on visual studio 2019. It compiles and run. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Let's go to the project properties (Alt-F7).
2. In 'Configuration' field please select: 'All Configurations'.
3. In 'Platform' field please select: 'All Platforms'.
4. Click: 'Configuration_Properties->C/C++->Language' and... look at "C++ Language Standard".

   Is there: "**<different options>**" instead of "ISO C++17 Standard..."??

   If yes, then change this to C++17 (**or later**) and compile your project again (MS Visual Studio).

Explanation: Visual Studio have ***individual*** properties for all Configuration/Platform combinations. So, it's easy possible to change some detail, which doesn't belong to the ***current*** compiler configuration.

It was an issue in my case at least. :-)
My compiler version: 17.2.1 .